# Trying to use xgboost for pairwise ranking

Tags: python, xgboost

Using the python API from the [documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core) of xgboost I am creating the train data by:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(file_path)
```

Here file_path is of `libsvm` format txt file. As I am doing pairwise ranking I am also inputting the length of the groups in the dtrain data that we just inputed:

```
dtrain.set_group(group_len_file)
```

and now I am training the model:

```
param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'rank:pairwise' }
param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'ndcg'

bst = xgb.train(param,dtrain,10)
```

Now I want to use `gridsearch`. So my question is how to use `gridsearch` from sklearn when I am inputing `DMatrix`?

Gennerally:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV 
param_test1 = {
            'max_depth':list(range(3,10,2)),
            'min_child_weiht':list(range(1,6,2))
            }
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=XGBClassifier(objective='rank:pairwise'),
                       param_grid = param_test1)
```

but `gsearch` doesnt have `train`. It only have `fit` which takes `X` and `y` as inputs and not `DMatrix`. Is there a way to do it?

And if not I can transform the `DMatrix` to be of format from `Dmatrix` => `X`, `y` but I can't find in documentation how to input `set_group` in that case? Any idea on it?

Comment: I guess, this has been resolved by now or is not relevant anymore?